# WMI Security Center productState clarification

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, wmi

I'm querying the WMI for **"SELECT * FROM AntivirusProduct"** on SecurityCenter2 (I'm on Windows 7 at the moment).

I'm having a hard time trying to find what do the numbers on **productState** mean, including AntiSpyware and Firewall aswell. Is there any reference for this out there? I want to make sure I can get the correct product states on any Vista or 7 machine (In case these numbers vary from machine to machine).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no official documentation on the `productState` values. The only info I could find is [this article](http://www.neophob.com/2010/03/wmi-query-windows-securitycenter2/) which makes assumptions about the `productState` value meaning based on the byte-by-byte analysis of the value.

Comment: The article really explains the situation on this issue. The reality is a shame though. Thanks for find Helen :)

Answer (score 2):

The `productState` values seem to be a bit set that is not documented except through an NDA with Microsoft. It should be possible to map the values returned with the products installed and their state. You could install a single AV product, record its state, then have its virus definitions go out of date, then check how the value changes. There seems to be a limited set of typical values.

**Reference:** https://bigfix.me/analysis/details/2998358

Here are the `productState` values I have found from 34 different AV products across over 10000 endpoints which could help reverse engineer the meaning:

( Decimal, Hex, Bit Set )

- 262144, 40000, 1000000000000000000
- 262160, 40010, 1000000000000010000
- 266240, 41000, 1000001000000000000
- 270336, 42000, 1000010000000000000
- 327680, 50000, 1010000000000000000
- 327696, 50010, 1010000000000010000
- 331776, 51000, 1010001000000000000
- 344064, 54000, 1010100000000000000
- 393216, 60000, 1100000000000000000
- 393232, 60010, 1100000000000010000
- 393472, 60100, 1100000000100000000
- 393488, 60110, 1100000000100010000
- 397312, 61000, 1100001000000000000
- 397328, 61010, 1100001000000010000
- 397568, 61100, 1100001000100000000
- 397584, 61110, 1100001000100010000
- 458752, 70000, 1110000000000000000
- 458768, 70010, 1110000000000010000
- 462848, 71000, 1110001000000000000
- 462864, 71010, 1110001000000010000

A friend of mine took this info much further and figured out that bit 3 of the bit set represents if the AV Definitions are outdated or not.

- bit 3 : AV Definitions Up to date or Outdated
- bit 17 : Auto Update Enabled or not
- bit 12 : Real time on access scanning
- bit 16 : Firewall
- bit 19 : AntiSpyware

See here: https://www.bigfix.me/analysis/details/2998101?force=true

Comment: Does this help answer the question?  How?  Can you infer what the productState values mean?

Comment: It does help to know that there don't seem to be an unlimited number of values and that it appears to be a bit set. It would require tracking down the differences between different sets of systems with only 1 bit difference in the bit set to try to see what is the difference between them and see if it can be changed in a predictable way to infer what the bits in the bit set represent.

It seems like the only way to find the answer is through reverse  engineering, and it is helpful when going down that path to have a large set of possible values to work from.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else, I've found that when converted to Hex, the third character pretty reliably indicates whether or not any particular antivirus product is enabled. (1 = Enabled, 0 = Disabled)

Here's a PowerShell one-liner I wrote to determine if Windows Defender is Enabled or not. You can replace the string to match whichever antivirus product you want.

```
Get-CimInstance -Namespace root/SecurityCenter2 -ClassName AntivirusProduct | ForEach-Object {if($($_.displayName) -eq "Windows Defender"){if("$($([Convert]::ToString($($_.productState), 16)).PadLeft(6,""0""))".Substring(2,1) -eq "1"){Write-Host "Windows Defender is Enabled"}else{Write-Host "Windows Defender is Disabled"}}}
```

I can't say for certain that every antivirus product correctly reports its product state, but I imagine all the mainstream ones must. I can confirm this also works with Symantec Endpoint Protection.

Comment: I dont understand Powershell fully but i was wondering why you padded. Other than that that I found a new productstate of 401664 for Windows Defender after figuring out why my third was a "1" unpadded and returning correctly that Defender its off (actually Snoozed).I padded and the third is a "2". The result wasstill right since it's only doing a simple is it 1 or not test....but I just wanted to note that for others to investigate too!

Comment: Additionally just googled a article that delved more https://mcpforlife.com/2020/04/14/how-to-resolve-this-state-value-of-av-providers/ it mentions key details in found in Win32 functions and enums for it (and even mentions this snooze state). Reccommend the read for any others.

This line is good "From MS support we received confirmation that the productState bitmask flag is 0x0000F000 and the value for Enable should be 0x1000."